# Logistic Regression classifier in Versions 12 vs 11.3

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics, machine-learning, function-comparison

There is a mysterious "LogisticRegression" method in MMA, which could be applied as a substitution for missing **multinomial logit** functionality.

In **version 11.3** I had the following simple 3-category classifier, which returns reasonable logit probabilities:

```
data = {{1, a}, {2, a}, {3, b}, {4, a}, {5, b}, {6, c}, {7, c}, {8, 
    b}, {9, c}};
cls = Classify[Rule @@@ data, Method -> "LogisticRegression"];
Quiet @ Plot[(Evaluate@
    Table[cls[x, {"Probability", i}], {i, {a, b, c}}]), {x, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"P(y=a | x)", "P(y=b | x)", "P(y=c | x)"}]
```

[image]

The same code produces weird results in **version 12** (Windows 10, 64-bit).

[image]

As one may see, it does classify somehow, though with `PlotRange -> {0,1}` this guy looks as follows:

[image]

**Question**. Can someone reproduce this behavior? If yes, is it a bug?

The relevant question is also [163662](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163662/classify-vs-logitmodelfit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is a bug. I executed your Code in M 11.1.1.
Using `ClassifierInformation[cls]` you get some Information About the Classifier.

[image]

Now I use M 12.0.0 and pass the regularization coefficients explicitly to the Classifier.

```
data = {{1, a}, {2, a}, {3, b}, {4, a}, {5, b}, {6, c}, {7, c}, {8, b}, {9, c}}; 
cls = Classify[Rule @@@ data, Method -> {"LogisticRegression", "L1Regularization" ->0., "L2Regularization" -> 1.}]; 
Quiet@Plot[(Evaluate@Table[cls[x, {"Probability", i}], {i, {a, b, c}}]), {x, 0, 10},PlotLegends -> {"P(y=a | x)", "P(y=b | x)", "P(y=c | x)"}]
```

The result is exactely the same as in M 11.
[image]

Comment: thank, you are right, it looks like a feature.

Comment: @garej If you want to reproduce M12 behaviour in M11 you have to set L2Regularization 1000. Unfortunately I have no insight about the underlying logic regarding the automatic determination of regularization coefficients.

Comment: If you just use `Classify[Rule @@@ data, Method -> {"LogisticRegression"}, TimeGoal -> 10]`, V12 picks more sensible regularization value of 10. It seems like you need to give it some time to find a good value.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, nice point, thank you.