# Classify and Predict results that I don't understand

Tags: machine-learning

I have a list of rules that has as the left hand side the font size and a letter and for the right hand side the space in pixels between this letter and the following letter. The data is from a postscript file. Two examples.

```
{8.5, "S"} -> 5.5165
{8.5, "\\251"} -> 2.363
```

The second example uses a character code to represent the actual character.

Here is the complete list of rules. Apologize for the length but I don't know what parts are and are not important.

```
letterRules={{8.5, "S"} -> 5.5165, {8.5, "P"} -> 5.6695, {8.5, "E"} -> 
  5.508, {8.5, "C"} -> 6.2985, {8.5, "I"} -> 2.5075, {8.5, "A"} -> 
  5.8225, {8.5, "D"} -> 6.2988, {8.5, "O"} -> 6.613, {8.5, "U"} -> 
  6.298, {8.5, "B"} -> 5.984, {8.5, "L"} -> 5.041, {8.5, "E"} -> 
  5.508, {8.5, "S"} -> 5.5165, {8.5, "I"} -> 2.5075, {8.5, "M"} -> 
  7.7095, {8.5, "P"} -> 5.6695, {8.5, "L"} -> 5.0405, {8.5, "O"} -> 
  6.6131, {8.5, "V"} -> 5.355, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.508, {8.5, "R"} -> 
  6.137, {8.5, "C"} -> 6.298, {8.5, "A"} -> 5.823, {8.5, "L"} -> 
  5.04, {8.5, "J"} -> 4.726, {8.5, "U"} -> 6.2985, {8.5, "M"} -> 
  7.7095, {8.5, "O"} -> 6.613, {8.5, "V"} -> 5.3546, {8.5, "E"} -> 
  5.508, {8.5, "R"} -> 6.137, {8.5, "C"} -> 6.299, {8.5, "A"} -> 
  5.822, {8.5, "L"} -> 5.041, {8.5, "O"} -> 6.613, {8.5, "P"} -> 
  5.6695, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.508, {8.5, "N"} -> 6.2985, {8.5, "I"} -> 
  2.5075, {8.5, "N"} -> 6.2985, {8.5, "P"} -> 5.6697, {8.5, "R"} -> 
  6.137, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.508, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.508, {8.5, "M"} -> 
  7.709, {8.5, "P"} -> 5.67, {8.5, "T"} -> 5.193, {8.5, "N"} -> 
  6.299, {8.5, "O"} -> 6.613, {8.5, "T"} -> 5.193, {8.5, "R"} -> 
  6.137, {8.5, "U"} -> 6.299, {8.5, "M"} -> 7.709, {8.5, "O"} -> 
  6.613, {8.5, "V"} -> 5.355, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.508, {8.5, "R"} -> 
  6.137, {8.5, "C"} -> 6.298, {8.5, "A"} -> 5.823, {8.5, "L"} -> 
  5.04, {8.5, "L"} -> 5.041, {8.5, "D"} -> 6.299, {8.5, "E"} -> 
  5.508, {8.5, "F"} -> 5.04, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.508, {8.5, "N"} -> 
  6.299, {8.5, "S"} -> 5.516, {8.5, "V"} -> 5.355, {8.5, "N"} -> 
  6.298, {8.5, "O"} -> 6.613, {8.5, "T"} -> 5.194, {8.5, "R"} -> 
  6.137, {8.5, "U"} -> 6.298, {8.5, "M"} -> 7.71, {8.5, "O"} -> 
  6.613, {8.5, "V"} -> 5.355, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.508, {8.5, "O"} -> 
  6.613, {8.5, "P"} -> 5.669, {8.5, "P"} -> 5.67, {8.5, "\\251"} -> 
  2.363, {8.5, "T"} -> 5.194, {8.5, "/"} -> 3.153, {8.5, "D"} -> 
  6.299, {8.5, "O"} -> 6.613, {8.5, "U"} -> 6.298, {8.5, "B"} -> 
  5.984, {8.5, "L"} -> 5.041, {8.5, "D"} -> 6.2985, {8.5, "I"} -> 
  2.5075, {8.5, "R"} -> 6.137, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.508, {8.5, "C"} -> 
  6.2985, {8.5, "C"} -> 6.2988, {8.5, "U"} -> 6.298, {8.5, "E"} -> 
  5.508, {8.5, "B"} -> 5.984, {8.5, "I"} -> 2.508, {8.5, "S"} -> 
  5.4315, {8.5, "L"} -> 4.9555, {8.5, "A"} -> 5.7375, {8.5, "C"} -> 
  6.2135, {8.5, "O"} -> 6.528, {8.5, "N"} -> 6.2135, {8.5, "V"} -> 
  5.27, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.423, {8.5, "N"} -> 6.2135, {8.5, "T"} -> 
  5.1085, {8.5, "I"} -> 2.4224, {8.5, "O"} -> 6.528, {8.5, "N"} -> 
  6.214, {8.5, "L"} -> 5.542, {8.5, "E"} -> 6.0605, {8.5, "A"} -> 
  6.409, {8.5, "D"} -> 6.9275, {9, "P"} -> 6.003, {9, "r"} -> 
  3.501, {9, "i"} -> 2.322, {9, "m"} -> 8.154, {9, "a"} -> 
  5.166, {9, "r"} -> 3.501, {9, "s"} -> 4.833, {9, "i"} -> 
  2.322, {9, "g"} -> 5.499, {9, "n"} -> 5.337, {9, "a"} -> 
  5.166, {9, "t"} -> 3.168, {9, "p"} -> 5.499, {9, "a"} -> 
  5.166, {9, "r"} -> 3.501, {9, "t"} -> 3.168, {9, "n"} -> 
  5.337, {9, "e"} -> 5.166, {9, "r"} -> 3.501, {9, "\\251"} -> 
  2.502, {9, "l"} -> 2.322, {9, "e"} -> 5.166, {9, "a"} -> 
  5.166, {9, "d"} -> 5.499, {8.5, "D"} -> 6.801, {8.5, "E"} -> 
  5.949, {8.5, "F"} -> 5.441, {8.5, "E"} -> 5.949, {8.5, "N"} -> 
  6.801, {8.5, "S"} -> 5.958, {8.5, "I"} -> 2.711, {8.5, "V"} -> 
  5.78, {8.5, "C"} -> 6.8, {8.5, "A"} -> 6.291, {8.5, "R"} -> 
  6.63, {8.5, "D"} -> 6.8, {8.5, "I"} -> 2.711, {8.5, "N"} -> 6.8}
```

I use both `Classify` and `Predict` with the training set.

```
letterClassify = Classify[letterRules, Method -> "NaiveBayes"];
letterPredict = Predict[letterRules, Method -> "NeuralNetwork"];
```

In general I am happy with the results. I created tables to show the results for a rule, for example rule #139 has a 9 pt font size, the letter ***d*** and a spacing of 5.499 pixels

[image]

The letter ***N*** with a font size of 8.5 occurs in a number of rules from 38 up to 153, various spacings with the majority around 6.3 pixels.

[image]

The columns are the rule number, the rule, the `Classify` result and the `Predict` result. Both `Classify` and `Predict` give reasonable results for the rule with one occurrence, ***d***, as well as the rule with multiple occurrences, ***N***.

However `Predict` gives an awful result for this single occurrence rule with a slash, ***/***.

[image]

and in the following example there are two single occurrences (because the font size differs) but `Classify` fails to treat them separately whereas `Predict` honors the font size.

[image]

Finally in this example there are many samples close to 5.8 but `Classify` picks the largest one which has only one occurrence.

[image]

I hope someone can help me to understand why I get mostly reasonable results but apparent failure in the above four cases.

Comment: It will be great to get an answer for this.  I get completely different answers for 12.0 and 12.1 (Windows 10) for `Predict` (and also different from your answers).  Some of the answers match up between the 3 versions (12.0, 12.1, and yours) for `Classifiy`.

Comment: @JimB, I cannot reproduce OP's results with default settings either (Mac, MM 12.0). With options `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` I could get a much better fit in both cases. Perhaps, it is similar problem that I had with `Classify` in this question [212597](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212597/logistic-regression-classifier-in-versions-12-vs-11-3).